# Would it be possible not to disable a button when opening a dialog in KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Basically, I have a button which I don't want to get disabled when I open `MDDialog`. Is that possible to do and what should be done to achieve it? I did some searching on this and haven't found anything useful.

Code example:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

kv = """
Screen:
    Button:
        text: 'dont disable me'
        pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: (0.2, 0.2)
        
    Button:
        text: 'open dialog'
        on_release: app.openDialog()
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.5}
        size_hint: (0.2, 0.2)
"""

class app(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
    def openDialog(self):
        dialog = MDDialog(title = 'hi',
                          size_hint = (0.2, 0.2))
        dialog.open()

app().run()
```

Comment: You cannot do that if you use `MDDialog` or 'Popup'. Those widgets are extensions of `ModalView` which is designed to disable your entire app while it is open. You can design your own dialog widget using the basic kivy or kivymd widgets (but not the `ModalView`) and just add it to your app root.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Okay, you can leave an answer if you want to close this question.